# Xcode 6 and iOS8: Architectures and Valid Architectures

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7, ios8

What should `Architectures` and `Valid Architectures` be set to in Xcode 6 and iOS 8?

I'm assuming I want to support the iPhone 4 running iOS7 through to the iPhone 6 running iOS8.

If it helps I currently have both set to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` which gives me:

```
Architectures: armv7, arm64
Valid Architectures: armv7, arm64
```

The iOS Default seems to be as above but with the addition of `armv7s` for `Valid Architectures`

Answer (score 3):

armv7s is for A6 SoC - the architecture of the A6 processor in the iPhone 5.

iPhone 5 can run with armv7 too. Armv7s is not mandatory for AppStore approval.

Comment: where can I find the list of supported devices and their architectures?